# Vba EXCEL: Listbox changes dimensions

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I'm writing a program as Excel Macro, and I have an issue with a Listbox.

Depending on the dimension of the screen, the Listbox changes its width.

The Listbox is **part of an user interface so it really shouldn't change dimensions**...

**Is there any way to anchor it tho a particular cell range?**

[image: here you see the Lb exceeding i]

Comment: I dont think there is a way to anchor it to a cell. You could try setting the width when code runs or when that sheet is selected. Why wouldnt you write this form into a userform, you would have much better control?

Comment: Thank you. I have it as Listbox because it should stay all the time there and not appear as separate window. Do you mean, with a userform i wouldn't have this problem?

Comment: The box wouldnt resize in a userform. but it would only work if you could move all your form (currently on that sheet) to a userform. Can you post a screenshot of the rest of that sheet?

Comment: I understand what you mean, i probably could. But i should rewrite many parts of the code since the program takes important values from that sheet for the calculation. It's a good idea indeed, but i think i will try to make it work this way before i have to rewrite everything.

Comment: It seems to be an ActiveX control, but can you confirm? Or is it a FormControl?

Comment: I think your idea of resizing the width when the program runs just worked fine actually. I now launch this subroutine when the file is opened: 
Sheets("Interface").ListBox1.Width = Sheets("Interface").Range("e:f").Width * 1.25

Comment: @R3uK yes it is an ActiveX

Answer (score 1):

Since a userform would be too much todo (as per op). You could try setting the width when the sheet is selected.

Would need to change the shape name and tweak the width to get the desired.

```
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("List Box 1")
shp.Width = 100
```

Comment: Yes it worked! And I set the width as the column width times a factor, so it is practically anchored to a cell range. Thanks everybody